# How to find a minimum?

Tags: c

I need to make a user enter the N (the number) between 7 and 12 ([7;12]). Then, I need to make the user enter the amount of numbers, which should be equal to N. Then, I need to output the sum of these numbers, find the average, min and max.
It works perfectly, except the minimum. When the count of numbers starts from 1, my program shows me that the minimum is 0. Thank you ahead...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int i = 0;
  int N;
  float numbers;
  float sum = 0;
  float average, min, max;

  printf("Choose a number between 7 and 12: ");
  scanf("%d", &N);

  if (N >= 7 && N <= 12) {
    printf("You have chosen: %d\n", N);
    printf("Now choose the amount of N numbers you have chosen: ");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      numbers = N; // the numbers the user enters must be
                   // strictly == N
      scanf("%f", &numbers);
      sum = sum + numbers;
      average = sum / numbers;

      if (numbers < min) {
        min = numbers;
      }

      if (numbers > max) {
        max = numbers;
      }
    }

    printf("The sum of your numbers is: %f\n The average of "
           "numbers: %f\n The max: %f\n The min: %f\n",
           sum, average, max, min);
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
    Choose a number between 7 and 12: 7                                                                                           
You have chosen: 7                                                                                                            
Now choose the amount of N numbers you have chosen: 1                                                                         
2                                                                                                                             
3                                                                                                                             
4                                                                                                                             
5                                                                                                                             
6                                                                                                                             
7                                                                                                                             
The sum of your numbers is: 28.000000                                                                                         
 The average of numbers: 4.000000                                                                                             
 The max: 7.000000                                                                                                            
 The min: 0.000000
```

Comment: Initialize min to something large and max to something small. Or set the initial values on the first iteration when the input number is both min and max.

Comment: If you have a possibility, write a piece of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `min` and `max` values are used uninitialized. On your platform/compiler, it *appears* that these are being default initialized to zero, but the C Standard does not require that.

To fix this issue, just initialize those variables (at the time of their declarations) to values that cannot be the final values (like the +/- values of the `FLT_MAX` constant, defined in `<float.h>`):

```c
    //...
    float average, min = FLT_MAX, max = -FLT_MAX;
    //...
```

Comment: Plus, even if you initialized a minimum thing to 0, you'd never get the actual minimum if all input data is positive because the initial value is smaller.

Comment: @starturtle Indeed. Which is why I also avoided the temptation of using `0` or `FLT_MIN` to initialize the `max` value! That would fail if all input numbers were negative.

Comment: but `-FLT_MAX`, because the semantics aren't the same as for integers. Indeed. *sigh*

Comment: Aside: `INF` a greater `float` than `FLT_MAX`.

Comment: @chux Good point if a little pedantic (I tried entering 1e+100 and it does, indeed, read an infinite number).

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this in a completely different fashion. Store the numbers in an array and then sort them. This is an example using integers, but it is very easy to modify for float usage.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// Bubble sort
void bubbleSort (int *numArray, int numElements) {
    int sorted = 0, temp;
    while (!sorted) {
        // Set this flag here
        sorted = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < numElements - 1; i++) {
            // Swaps the numbers
            if (numArray [i] > numArray [i + 1]) {
                temp = numArray [i];
                numArray [i] = numArray [i + 1];
                numArray [i + 1] = temp;
                sorted = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

float calcAverage (int numArray [], int numElements) {
  float avg = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) avg += numArray [i];

  return avg / numElements;
}

int main() {
    int numElements = 0;
    // Ensure they actually enter a number!
    while (numElements < 7 || numElements > 12) {
        printf ("Please enter a number between 7 and 12: ");
        // Input validation is always important in my opinion.
        if (!scanf ("%d", &numElements)) {
            printf ("ERROR: NaN value passed! ");
        }
        else if (numElements < 7 || numElements > 12) printf ("ERROR: Invalid number! ");
        // Clear the buffer
        while (getchar() != '\n');
    }

    printf ("You have chosen: %d.\n", numElements);
    
    // Create our array and store our current number.
    int numArray [numElements], fGood;

    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
      // Reset this flag at the beginning of the loop
      fGood = 0;

      while (!fGood) {
        printf ("Please enter value %d: ", i + 1);
        // Assume it's a good value
        fGood = 1;

        if (!scanf ("%d", &numArray [i])) {
          printf ("ERROR: Invalid value passed! ");
        }
        while (getchar() != '\n');
      }
    }

    bubbleSort (numArray, numElements);
    printf ("Average of entered numbers: %.2f\nMinimum value: %d\nMaximum value: %d\n", calcAverage(numArray, numElements), numArray [0], numArray [numElements - 1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inventive, but unnecessarily complex and certain to be shot down at code review time.

Comment: OP's values are as `float`.  Important difference (Infinity, NaN) not addressed here with an `int`  example.  IAC, standard C library `qsort()` certainly more efficient than `bubbleSort()`.